# Validates if a person is older than 18 or have 18 based on birthday

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a little code to check if a person have 18 years or is older given her/his birthday. This is what I have done til now:

```
function validateAge(birthday, minage, separator) {
    if (!parseInt(minage)) {
        return false;
    }

    var $split = birthday.split(separator);

    var $dateFullYear = $split[2];
    var $dateMonth = $split[1];
    var $dateDay = $split[0];

    var $tempDate = new Date($dateFullYear + minage, $dateMonth, $dateDay);

    if ($tempDate <= new Date()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return false;

}
```

But I give always a valid response when for example if I call the function with this parameters: `validateAge('09/09/2014', 18, '/')` it should return `false` since it's today. I'm making a mistake somewhere but I don't see it, can any help me?

Comment: You don't need `else` with `return false` if you `return false` in the end at all.

Comment: @dsuckau you mean remove the `else` from conditional? Right?

Comment: Why all the dollar signs? It's not PHP/Perl ;)

Comment: @Wolph It's not even jQuery variables pointing out to selected elements.

Comment: @ReynierPM doesn't solve your main problem, was just a side notice. But yes.

Comment: Your example returns false for me.

Comment: You should parse your splitted values too.

Comment: Return false for me. Maybe erase your browser cache.

Comment: @kol try with this one instead `validateAge('09/09/1990', 18, '/')` which should be valid since a person born in 1990 by now should have 24 years, that's return FALSE too

Comment: @kol and this is wrong since that should returns TRUE meaning that person has 18 years or is older than that, that's the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should parse the `split` statements like so and subtract one from the month (zero-based):

```
var $dateFullYear = parseInt($split[2],10);
var $dateMonth = parseInt($split[1],10)-1;
var $dateDay = parseInt($split[0],10);
```

Comment: Don't forget the radix.

Answer (score 1):

The month needs to be zero-based.

```
new Date(2014, 9, 9) // Thu Oct 09 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT)
```

You would expect the month `9` to be September, but it's actually October because January is 0.  This is throwing off your comparison.

Comment: Good call, I forgot about the add/concat that was happening.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see an example:

```
validateAge('09/09/1990', 18, '/')
```

In this case, your code will do this:

```
var $tempDate = new Date('1990' + 18, '09', '09');
```

which is the same as

```
var $tempDate = new Date(199018, 9, 9);
```

This problem can be solved by parsing the parts of `birthday`:

```
var $dateFullYear = parseInt($split[2]);
var $dateMonth = parseInt($split[1]) - 1; // months are zero based
var $dateDay = parseInt($split[0]);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what @mccannf and others suggest in first so problem is fixed now, thanks all of yours

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `$dateFullYear` in a `parseInt` - its trying to add a string and an integer together and giving you the wrong date.

```
var $tempDate = new Date(parseInt($dateFullYear, 10) + minage, $dateMonth, $dateDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try rewrite your function as follows, where the month is zero-based:

```
function validateAge(birthday, minage, separator) {
    if (!parseInt(minage)) {
        return false;
    }
    var split = birthday.split(separator);
    var dateFullYear = split[2];
    var dateMonth = split[1];
    var dateDay = split[0];
    var mydate = new Date();

    mydate.setFullYear(dateFullYear, dateMonth-1, dateDay);

    var currdate = new Date();
    var setDate = new Date();         
    setDate.setFullYear(mydate.getFullYear() + minage, dateMonth-1, dateDay);

    return (currdate - setDate) > 0;

}

var valid = validateAge('09/09/2014', 18, '/');
console.log(valid); // false
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/ys6mw0k8/)**